# How to Delete Multiple Rows With Multiple SELECT Statements In WHERE Clause in DB2

Tags: db2

In the given `inventory` table below:

| SKU | COST | DATE `YYMMDD` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202114000 | 0 | 210109 |
| 202114000 | 12 | 210228 |
| 202115000 | 50 | 210108 |
| 202115000 | 30 | 210109 |
| 202116000 | 54 | 210103 |
| 202116000 | 60 | 210301 |
| 202116000 | 100 | 210605 |

I want to retain SKU with the latest date and remove all others, and just retaining one SKU per row.

My query script goes:

```
SELECT *
FROM `inventory`
WHERE
    INUMBR IN (
        SELECT 
            SKU
        FROM
            `inventory`
        WHERE
            SKU IN (
                SELECT
                    SKU
                FROM
                    `inventory`
                GROUP BY
                    SKU
                HAVING
                    COUNT(*) > 1
                ORDER BY
                    SKU
            )
        GROUP BY
            SKU
        ORDER BY
            SKU
    )
    AND
    DATE IN (
        SELECT
            MIN (DATE) as DATE
        FROM
            `inventory`
        WHERE
            SKU IN (
                SELECT
                    SKU
                FROM
                    `inventory`
                GROUP BY
                    SKU
                HAVING
                    COUNT(*) > 1
                ORDER BY
                    SKU
            )
        GROUP BY
            SKU
        ORDER BY
            SKU
    )
ORDER BY
    SKU
```

However, this script is problematic. Why? because it will delete the two rows with the `SKU` `20211500` because, on the second `IN` criteria in the `WHERE` clause, two of `DATE`s will match: `210109` and `210108`. How can I improve my query?

NOTE: The table is just an example, I will be dealing with millions of rows here.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete from a derived table as long as there is a bijection to the underlaying base table. Here I enumerate the rows per sku in reversed order and delete all but the first one:

```
delete from ( 
    select sku, cost, dt
         , row_number() over (partition by sku 
                              order by dt desc) as rn 
    from inventory
) 
where rn > 1


select * from inventory

SKU                COST        DT          
------------------ ----------- ------------
202114000                   12 210228      
202115000                   30 210109      
202116000                  100 210605
```

Note, I used dt as a column name since date is a reserved word. I also assumed that sku, dt is the primary key of the table, if not the result will be non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it. I will just use `MAX`, instead of `MIN`. And I just also learned that you can give two parameters in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE
FROM `inventory`
WHERE (SKU, DATE)
    NOT IN (
        SELECT
           SKU,
           MAX(DATE) as DATE
        FROM `inventory`
        WHERE
           SKU IN (
              SELECT
                 SKU
              FROM
                 `inventory`
              GROUP BY
                 SKU
              HAVING
                 COUNT(*) > 1
              ORDER BY
                 SKU
           )
        GROUP BY
            SKU
        ORDER BY
            SKU
    )
    AND
    SKU NOT IN (
            SELECT
                SKU
            FROM
                `inventory`
            GROUP BY
                SKU
            HAVING
                COUNT(*) = 1
            ORDER BY
                SKU
        )
    AND 
    SKU!= 0
```

Let me know if there is still a way to further improve this query.